# How to pass a slice of arguments to a function in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a main function that passes a slice of arguments to another function in my script:

```
main() {
  other_fn "${@:2}"
}

other_fn() {
  for i in "${@}"; do
    echo "Processing $i"
  done
}
```

When I run `my_script.sh process x y z`, I expect it to output three lines of outputs, but I only see one line: `Processing x y z`.

What can I do to make the passed arguments work like an array instead of a whole string?

Comment: How are you passing arguments to the `main` function? I'd recommend adding `set -x` to the beginning of the script, so you can see what's going on as it runs.

Comment: I run it as `main "$@"` at the end of my script.

Comment: It seems like `other_fn "${@:2}"` becomes `other_fn 'x y z'` when I run my script, I don't know how to get rid of the quotes.

Comment: What bash version?

Comment: It seems to be caused by a line that set `IFS` to `$'\n\t'`.

Comment: I think you'll need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can actually see it happen. Without we could only guess.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, I tried to create such a minimal script after reading your comment and figured out the answer while trying to reproduce the problem. Here's my attempt to fix `kubectx -d` on Github: https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/pull/344

Answer (score 1):

You did not show in your script, how you are calling *main*. When I add a

```
main "$@"
```

at the end of the script, it displays the items y and z on separate lines. It does not display x of course. From this I assume that, you have an error in invoking your *main*  function.

Also, it depends on how you call your script. You need to invoke it as *bash* script. To verify this, you should output your `BASH_VERSION` **inside** the script.
Hence, the script becomes

```
# this is script x.sh
echo $BASH_VERSION
main() {
  other_fn "${@:2}"
}
other_fn() {
  for i in "${@}"; do
    echo "Processing $i"
  done
}
main "$@"
```

Running it as

```
bash x.s x y z
```

prints

```
4.4.12(3)-release
Processing y
Processing z
```

May I suggest that you copy my script and invoke it in exactly the same way as I did?